# How can we change the height of a header box

Tags: boxes, height, baposter

In my poster done using `baposter`, I need to change the height of the `\headerbox.`

for example, I have this example:

```
\headerbox{Results}{name=results,column=2,span=2,row=1,below=results,above=references}{ body….}
```

here the width is like 2 column and determined by `span=2` and the other parameters are about the position, but about the height ? Because, in my case, I have a `\headerbox` and its contents are overflow despite that there is a space below this `\headerbox`. How can I change its height? thanks to help me

Comment: A look into `baposter.cls` reveals that there is a key value `boxheaderheight` which has to be specified if some other value is wanted. `\headerbox{Results}{boxheaderheight=5cm, (rest as in your example)}{body} will probably do...

Answer (score 3):

Since no more information is given, it is just a guess:

```
\documentclass[a0paper]{baposter}

\begin{document}

\begin{poster}{}{}{}{}{}


\headerbox{William Shakespeare}{boxheaderheight=1cm,span=4,column=0}{
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
When shall we three meet again?\par
In thunder, lightning or in rain?\par
}
\end{poster}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thanks but this changes just the size of the title of the box header, I need to change the size of the body.

Comment: In your first post, there was no information about the issue with body. Another look into `baposter.cls`  (at about line number 830) resulted in now knowing about the `height` option to header box, which is to be given in % of column height. Add `height=4` or something to the `headerbox` options

Answer (score 2):

An easy and not really good solution is to use `\vspace{3cm}` in the box you want to increase the heigth. This way you can adjust until both boxes have the same length you desire.

Comment: Welcome, can you add a small example showing exactly how to use the command?

Comment: What if the content of the boxes changes? Do we need to adjust the `\vspace{...}` each time? As it stands, it's a rather a comment

Comment: Given that the OP didn't post a MWE I think that this is a reasonable answer.

Comment: This also works with negative numbers in case you want to shrink the box. Just make sure you write it INSIDE the box, not after it.